# Multiple restarts after installtion

Tags: c#, .net

My c# application starts an installer which may install several patches. After the installer is closed my app may need to restart the system multiple times for each patch installed. What is the best way to do this?

Currently i am calling the shutdown process with `/f /l` arguments for single restart.

Comment: Why would it need to restart multiple times? Why not install all of the patches and then restart once?

Comment: I agree with @M.Babcock, but I'll go one step further. Why should a user-mode application *ever* have to restart the entire system? Only Windows components should have to do this, and even they don't all require it.

Comment: @CodyGray - I agree in principle but I know most of the applications I install require a reboot (whether waranted or not). If this truly is a installer process then I can see their point... just not multiple times for sure.

Comment: I don't think I've installed an application that required a restart (other than something like Visual Studio, which does install system components) since I upgraded from Windows 98. Even if my memory is fuzzy, the point is that this should be exceptionally rare, and I suspect that most of the applications that require a restart only do so because of laziness on the part of the developers, rather than any real technical necessity.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. These are OS updates and all I know is each patch needs a restart.

Comment: Which OS updates? Can you postpone the restart for each of them until you install the last one? That's generally supported. You can check the documentation for specifics, or get someone here to Google it for you if you specify the updates required.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, it's generally a bad idea for an installer to redistribute windows updates.  First there is the problem of licensing ( they generally aren't redistributable ) and then there is the problem of the rabbit hole you create in taking ownership of patching the customers computer.  It's usually better to just have your installer check for situations that will break your app and tell the user before exiting the installer.

Answer (score 0):

If indeed this is necessary, it seems like you could just set the RunOnce registry key before shutting down if there are any remaining patches.

Setting keys in C#:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx

Run and RunOnce registry keys:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was thinking if i can keep a count of no of restarts required in the registry and at login decrement the count on   every restart.

Comment: If you use RunOnce correctly, you shouldn't even need a count.  Just set it when one patch is done if you need to do another.  If it's the last one, don't set it.